# Create function endpoint: endpoint: /api/product/get_data/{id}

Tags: laravel, api, rest

i have two tables, 'products' and 'sellers'

```
`Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('seller_id');
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->string('product_size');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('sellers');`

`Schema::create('sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('seller_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });`
```

**How to** create function for show only **product_name**, **product_size** and **seller_name** aslo how to create validation for **product_size** need bigger then 2(for example)

i create ProductResource

```
        `phone_name' => $this->product_name,
        'display_size' => $this->product_size,
        'seller_name' => SellerResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('seller'))`
```

but return only product_name and product_size.

And create relationships one to many

**I try to:** create validate on method 'show'

```
       response()->validate([
        'product_size' => ['numeric|min:5']
        ]);
```

try to filter bu operator 'like'.
try to create 'Requests'

```
    public function rules(){
    return [
        'product_size' => 'numeric|min:5'
    ];
}
```

data needs only show and validate

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [visit the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, and search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: Please read: [Writing The Validation Logic](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) and [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli I have displayed the data that I need, but I do not know how to validate it

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa i need validate or filter method show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds like you need to create a custom validator. Does that make sense?

The custom validator might look like

```
class ProductSizeValidationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'product_size' => 'numeric|min:2',
        ];
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this. UNTESTED, I hope this makes sense
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    $this->validate(request(), (new ProductSizeValidationRequest)->rules());

    return new ProductResource($product);
```

Comment: This code didn't work, I still see size less than 5

Comment: I made a mistake I did numeric|min:2 just change the 2 to 5 should be ok